What steps do I take to forgive my aunt “biblically”
My aunt stole money from me. I was hurt, balled my eyes out; not because she stole but because I felt betrayed by someone I helped numerous times. I forgave her in my heart but someone told me that Im supposed to tell her that I forgive her. Note: She is a believer in christ and she lives in Nc while I’m currently in Md.

You should ultimately seek advice from a trusted spiritual advisor, such as a pastor. That said, we can say some things about biblical forgiveness generally.
Biblical forgiveness between Christians follows upon the kind of forgiveness God gives to His children. The Lord's prayer asks God to forgive us as we forgive others. This shows that we are to imitate God's forgiveness in our own forgiveness.
Notably, God only forgives us when we repent. The parable of the wicked servant (Matthew 18:21-35) shows that God forgives the servant who asks for forgiveness, but that servant refuses to forgive his fellow servant who also asks for forgiveness. He is therefore punished, and the master (God) rescinds his forgiveness of the servant's debt. The servant should have imitated his master in forgiving his fellow servant when his fellow servant asked for forgiveness. The master was not going to forgive the servant's debt until the servant begged him to.
We are called to forgive others when they repent, but if they are unrepentant, we are under no obligation to forgive them. We should still love them and still desire their good, since that is an imitation of Christ. Romans 5:8 says this "But God demonstrates his own love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us." He loves us even while we are His enemies, but forgiveness and love are not the same.
